# Определение взаимно-зависимых структур в C++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, struct

В программе у меня есть две структуры A и B и я пытаюсь последовательно определить их, при этом у них обоих есть поля, являющиеся ссылками на объект другой структуры.
Структура примерно такая:

```
struct A{
 vector<B*> name;
 A(){
     name = {};
 }
};
struct B{
 A* name;
 B(A* name){
     this->name = name;
 }
};
```

Но при запуске компиляции выдается ошибка: `'B' was not declared in this scope ...`
Я пробовал выносить это в отдельные файлы, создавать пустой класс B перед A: `struct B;`,
но ничего так и не получилось сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaration спасет отца русской демократии :)

```
struct B;

struct A
{
    vector<B*> name;
    A(){
        name = {};
    }
};
struct B{
    A* name;
    B(A* name){
        this->name = name;
    }
};
```